# How to retrieve the record closest in time to current record partitioning by the negative of the row value

Tags: sql, datetime, window-functions

I have a list of records that represent inventory corrections. For each record I want to find the corresponding negative value record and understand how close together they happened.

E.g if the corrected_quantity was -4 for a given row. I want to find the nearest row that is +4 and look up the created_time column to understand how long there was between these two actions.

```
(lag(created_time,1) over (partition by it.product_id,abs(quantity_change),sign(quantity_change) order by created_time asc)) as previous_correction,
(lag(created_time,-1) over (partition by it.product_id,abs(quantity_change),sign(quantity_change) order by created_time asc)) as subsequent_correction
```

The problem with this lag function is it obviously converts the -4 into +4 and so just ends up finding the row that had a +4 corrected_quantity - which is not what I need.

Data looks like this: (sorry I don't know how to format it like a table)

```
CREATED_TIME                    QUANTITY_CHANGE
2020-07-07 12:42:59.901 +0000      -12
2020-07-07 12:42:04.916 +0000       12
2020-07-07 11:51:57.236 +0000       40
2020-07-07 11:51:57.223 +0000       -40
2020-07-07 06:46:32.955 +0000       3
2020-07-07 06:46:10.592 +0000       -3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the greatest time before, you can use a cumulative conditional maximum:

```
select max(case when quantity_change < 0 then created_time end) over
           (partition by product_id, abs(quantity_change)
            order by created_time
           )
```

If you want to do this for both positive and negative values, then use `case`:

```
select (case when quantity_change > 0
             then max(case when quantity_change < 0 then created_time end) over
                      (partition by product_id, abs(quantity_change)
                       order by created_time
                      )
             else max(case when quantity_change > 0 then created_time end) over
                      (partition by product_id, abs(quantity_change)
                       order by created_time
                      )
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is I'm not looking for the max or the min but rather the record that's closest in time. For example there could be another adjustment for -4 in the distant past which this code would pick up as the answer.

Comment: @SéamusBeirne . . . This returned the timestamp that matches closest in time.  If you want the full record, you can `join` that information back in.

Comment: The only issue I have with your code is it doesn't seem to be able to look into the future to get the closest correction. E.g. if an opposite correction happens AFTER a given correction I want that to be assigned to it. Is there a way to alter the code to account for this?

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your code and changed max to min and ordered by `desc `and this helps me to get the closest correction in the future. Then I've done a `least` with `timestampdiff`to find the one that's closest.

Comment: @SéamusBeirne . . . Your query uses `lag()` so I figured that you wanted the closest value before a given row.

Comment: I use ``lag`` with ``-1`` instead of using ``lead``. Thanks a lot though this solved my problem. I then just used some logic to find which inventory correction was closer in time, the previous or the subsequent.